# How save float32 array to double precision from gorm

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, go-gorm

I try save float32 in golang to db (postgresql). I use gorm. My Field in struct:

```
    Cluster [512]float32 `gorm:"column:cluster;type:float[]"`
```

When i save to db, log mode show me right sql, but write error:

> converting argument $3 type: unsupported type [512]float32, a array

Сan anyone have an idea how to tell the postgres what to do?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered a problem like this. 
I suggest you make you own type for your array that implements

> type Valuer interface

and

> type Scanner interface

from `database/sql` package.

Also you could try `pq.Float64Array` type instead of float slice (I know that is float64, but it is the only type they have) from `github.com/lib/pq`.

Comment: Link that helped me with the solution of the question: https://gowalker.org/github.com/lib/pq#Float64Array_Value